# Overloading << operator to output matrix in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Hi im trying to overload the << operator in order to output a matrix as a table. I have started implementing and have finished it, but im not sure if i did it right as im getting errors that dont make sense to me. This is my 1st time overloading << so im not sure if i even did this right. Please help.

Error(edited):

```
In file included from MatrixTester.cpp:3:
Matrix.h:16: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘operator’
In file included from MatrixTester.cpp:4:
Matrix.cpp:132: error: ‘std::ostream& Matrix::operator<<(std::ostream&, const Matrix&)’ must take exactly one argument
MatrixTester.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
MatrixTester.cpp:15: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << matrix’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:108: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& (.....
```

My MatrixTester.cpp:

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include "Matrix.cpp"
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int row,column;
    cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    cin >> row;
    cout << "Enter number of column: ";
    cin >> column;
    Matrix matrix(row,column);
    cout<<matrix;
    vector<int> rowVec;
    vector<int> colVec;
    bool cont = true;

    do{
        cout << "Enter column index: ";
        int index;
        cin >> index;

        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
            cout << "Enter an integer: ";
            int num;
            cin >> num;
            colVec.push_back(num);  
        }
        if (matrix.setColumn(colVec,index) == false){
            cout << "Unable to modify matrix: Index might be out of bounds " << endl;
        }else{
            cont = false;
        }
    }while(cont == true);
    cout<<matrix;   

    cout << "Enter row index: ";
    int index;
    cin >> index;
    rowVec = matrix.getRow(index);
    for (int i =0;i<rowVec.size();i++){
        cout << rowVec[i] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    double avg = matrix.average();
    cout<<"Average: " <<avg<<endl;

    Matrix m2(rowVec.size(), colVec.size());
    rowVec = matrix.getRow(1);
    for (int i=0; i <= row-1; i++){
        cout <<"for l" <<endl;
        m2.setRow(rowVec,i);
    }

    cout <<"Adding..." <<endl;
    Matrix m3(row,column); 
    m3 = matrix + m2;
    cout<<m3;

    cout <<"Subtract..." <<endl; 
    m3 = matrix - m2;
    cout<<m3;

    cout <<"Multiply..." <<endl; 
    m3 = matrix * m2;
    cout<<m3;
}
```

Matrix.h

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H 

#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class Matrix{
    public:
        Matrix();
        Matrix(int r, int c);
        bool setRow(vector<int> row, int r);
        bool setColumn(vector<int> col, int c);
        vector<int> getRow(int index);
        vector<int> getCol(int index);
        void indentityMatrix();
        ostream& Matrix operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix& m);
        double average();
        Matrix operator+(Matrix m);
        Matrix operator-(Matrix m);
        Matrix operator*(Matrix m);
        Matrix operator/(Matrix m);
    private:
        int row, column;
        vector< vector<int> > matrix;
};

#endif
```

Overload operator<< in Matrix.cpp (edited)

```
ostream& Matrix::operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix& m){
    vector<int> vecRow;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        vecRow = m.getRow(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++){
            out << vecRow[j];
            out <<"\t";
        }
        out << endl;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Im still getting the errors

Comment: may I ask why you include "Matrix.cpp"?

Comment: You might want to rearrange the header files inclusions a little. Any don't do `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @Creris my assignment asks for a Matrix.cpp and a tester class that is separate to the matrix.cpp. Thats why i have the include.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg whats wrong with my header files inclusions? also, the using namespace std; is what my prof wants me to use.

Comment: `vecRow = m.getRow(i);` this is copying the whole vector each time. Is that really what you want to do? Why not store it in a reference or pointer. Also pass Matrix m by const reference.

Comment: im not familiar with reference or pointers. So vec = m.getRow(i) gets the numbers in row i and copies them to vecRow so that it can be easier to output.

Comment: The semicolon I added was for the prototype. You need to remove it from the definition of the operator (i.e. between the `)` and `{` there should be no semicolon).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight whoops, i had fixed that in my code but forgot to remove it from the post, but im still getting the errors,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since dasblinkenlight seems to be temporarily distracted, here's how the `operator<<` should be declared and defined:

Matrix.h:

```
class Matrix{
    public:

        //ostream& Matrix operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix& m);
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix& m);

};
```

Matrix.cpp:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix& m) {
```

Comment: whats the friend for?

Comment: great thanks, my errors went from a dozen to just one: Matrix.cpp:135: error: passing ‘const Matrix’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > Matrix::getRow(int)’ discards qualifiers. What does that mean?

Comment: @a22asin: You have told the compiler that the `getRow` function modifies it's matrix, so it won't let you call that on an immutable matrix.  So mark the function as const in the declaration for the class: `vector<int> getRow(int index) const;` (You probably want to do that to `getCol` and `average` as well, and probably `operator+` and similar.

Comment: getRow simply gets the rows, its not a mutator function. Does that still mean i have to make it const?

Comment: i love u Mooing Duck, dasblinkenlight and everyone else who helped me! it works!

Comment: @a22asin: If you do NOT make it `const`, then the compiler thinks it's a mutator function.  If it's NOT a mutator function, it SHOULD have `const`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that you have `#include "Matrix.cpp"` in your code. It is wrong all by itself, but in this case it also causes the "incomplete type" error, because it is included ahead of the `<iostream>` header.

You should never need to `#include` a cpp file. If you did so to fix the link issue because operator `<<` has been missing, the proper way to fix it is to compile your cpp files on the same command, compile them separately without linking and then linking, or to include them as separate items of your IDE project (if you are using a development environment).

Note that you are passing `Matrix` to the operator by value. This is suboptimal, because your entire matrix gets copied simply for the purpose of being printed. Generally, you should pass the item being printed to the operator `<<` by constant reference:

```
// This goes into the Matrix.h header:
friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Matrix& p);

// This goes into Matrix.cpp implementation:
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix& m) {
    ...
}
```

EDIT (Thanks for a great hint, Mooing Duck!)

Comment: ok, my Matrix.cpp is my main code, the tester class is just for me to test my class, i need them separate for my assignment so thats why i have the #include "Matrix.cpp"

Comment: @dasblinkednlight im using a linux shell with the command g++.

Comment: no you dont include your cpp files from the file you have your main inside. You **`link`** then together using compiler

Comment: Im now getting " ‘std::ostream& Matrix::operator<<(std::ostream&, const Matrix&)’ must take exactly one argument" error when i use your code.

Comment: @Creris how would i do that?

Comment: I have no idea how gcc/g++ works with command line, so I wont help you with this one

Comment: @a22asin Remove the `#include "Matricx.cpp"` from `MatrixTester.cpp` and in the g++ command like where you have `MatrixTester.cpp` follow that immediately by `Matrix.cpp`.  That said, if you're running under Linux I'd very strongly recommend getting a copy of Eclipse and the CDT for it.  That'll give you an IDE to develop with, and more importantly to debug with.  If you have Windows as an option, grab a copy of the latest Visual Studio Express.

Comment: @a22asin It looks like your declaration in the `Matrix.h` is not there or different from the definition that has const reference. To compile and link several files with gcc compiler, list them together, for example, like this: `g++ Matrix.cpp Tester.cpp main.cpp`

Comment: @dgnuff i did that, but now im getting that Matrix matrix wasnt declared in the scope in my Tester class

Comment: @a22asin Your tester class need to include the header for the `Matrix`. The header for the matrix needs to provide a forward declaration, also known as "a prototype" (but not a definition) for the operator `<<`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Hint: `Matrix::operator<<` means it's a member

Comment: This is quite frustrating :( . Does the include affect why im getting this error or is it just something i shouldn't do? if its the 2nd, can we ignore that for now and focus on the overloading. the Testerclass isnt the assignment its the Matrix class and header.

Comment: @a22asin Please take a look at the edit. It looks like you are using the member syntax for your operator, not a free-standing syntax. I didn't realize that because you did not show your `Matrix.h` header.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight didnt think i needed to, but i added it above

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: You, uh, got the whole `operator<<` thing wrong.  I just dropped a hint because I figured it was an oversight, but now your code is for giving a stream to a matrix rather than the other way 'round.